# Filter function in Scala not working

Tags: list, scala, if-statement, for-loop, filter

```
   def filter(data : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {


  if(data.length == 0){
  return data;

  }else{
    var list: List[Int] = List();
    var index = 0;

    for((value,index) <- data.zipWithIndex){
        if(list(index) == list(index+1){
                list = value :: list;
                //println(list(index));
        }
    }




  }

    return list

  }
}
```

Im having trouble with my function. 'data' is an array of ints and this function needs to filter all duplicates that are next to each other. For example {1,2,3,3,4,3,1} would be filters to {1,2,3,4,3,1}. This function is currently throwing array out of bounds exceptions. My knowledge in scala is very limited so please keep all answers simple due to the lack of knowledge. Thanks for all help provided :D.

Comment: `index+1` is out of range on the last list element. Also you're building the list in reverse order. You might want to use a `ListBuffer` or use a recursive approach instead of using a `for`.

Comment: My idea was to copy the list into another using .reverse once I got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a list via an index and creating another list for results is kind of a code smell. Here's another approach with recursion and pattern matching which makes for a rather simple solution.

```
def filterNextTo(xs: List[Int]):List[Int] = xs match{
  case h :: ht :: t => if(h == ht) filterNextTo(xs.tail) else h :: filterNextTo(xs.tail)
  case h :: Nil => List(h)
  case Nil => Nil
}
```

Test case:

```
scala> xs
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1)

scala> filterNextTo(xs)
res8: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1)
```

This can also be done with `zip`, `filter`, and `map` but requires a bit of tuple wrangling and handling a special case which I think is less elegant.

Updated to add a tail recursive version per @Paul's comment:

```
def filterNextTo(xs: List[Int]) = {
  @tailrec
  def filterNextToR(xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match{
    case h :: ht :: t if (h == ht) => filterNextToR(xs.tail, acc)
    case h :: ht :: t if (h != ht) => filterNextToR(xs.tail, h :: acc)
    case h :: t  => (h :: acc).reverse
  }
  filterNextToR(xs, List[Int]())
}
```

Comment: Is what you have done "head, tail"? I'm very new to this language at the moment

Comment: Yes. It's decomposing the list to get the head, head of the tail, and the tail.

Comment: Not tail-recursive though so will stack overflow on long lists

Comment: The last two case statements can be replaced by one: `case ys => ys` as f`ilterNextTo` just returns its input in both those cases

Answer (score 1):

I think a fold is neater than the explicit recursion, and will work on long lists:

```
ls match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case h :: t => t.foldLeft(List(h))
                             ((a, b) => if (a.head == b) a 
                                         else b :: a)
                              .reverse
  }    
//> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1,1,5,5,6,6)  
  val y = list.sliding(2).toList

  val x =y.filter(x=> (x.head != x.tail.head)).map(_.head) :+ (y.reverse.filter(x=> x.head !=x.tail.head)).head.tail.head
```